# How to show a section of HTML using webview?

Tags: html, iphone, xcode, webview, uiwebview

I have been searching through questions trying to find an answer but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing. I want to display just a section of my HTML in webview.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 640.0)];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
webView.delegate = self ;
[webView loadRequest:requestObj]; 
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

This works perfectly displaying the whole webpage. But lets say I want to just display a certain div, what do I have to do?

I have tried adding in getElemntByID and getElementsByClass but it doesn't seem to work for me..

Answer (score 0):

the answer of your question.

```
   NSString *htmlPage = @"<html><body><h1>StackOverFlow</h1></body></html>";
    [yourWebView loadHTMLString:htmlPage baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: When I am putting in my HTML I am getting errors of use of undeclared identifiers. Its a widget on a website I'm trying to show.

Comment: which one is undeclared

Comment: its expecting ; at id's in the HTML. 'iframe id="twitter-widget-0' You see i want to display this iframe.

Comment: This is what I have: `@"<head><div class="container"><div class="row"><section class="span12" role="main"><div class="row"><div class="span3"><a class="timeline" data-dnt="true"</a></div></div></section></div></script></body></html>";`